# What is a ghost page?

Tags: web, seo, html

Can somebody please tell me what exactly a ghost page is? How can we create a ghost page?
I have very little information about it, like ghost pages are used by firms for promotional purposes.

Comment: [This explanation of a phantom page](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/phantom-page) could be interesting. In my opinion it's just another name for "ghost page" ... and it's evil! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, it's deliberate deception of search engines for SEO purposes. It's bad practice.

**Longer answer:**

Say you're optimizing your cheese-selling site. You want people to find it when googling "cheese". So you would create a bunch of content where "cheese" has a high keyword density of 12 % or so. Of course, this renders the page pretty useless for the user - the user just wants an image, some data on the cheese and a header, but that isn't SEO-friendly enough for you.

So, you'll create all the content you need for your SEO purposes and serve that up - in an if/else statement. Basically, if the visiting computer is GoogleBot, you'll serve up all that great text. If it's **not** GoogleBot, you'll serve up correct content.

So a Ghost Page (more accurately known as Shadow Page) is pretty much just a (bad) way for you to get ranking that you don't deserve.